# Spark DataFrameWriter ignoreNullFields not working

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame containing multiple nulls with different schema

```
df.show(false)
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|null|null|1   |a   |
+----+----+----+----+
```

I am trying to write this dataframe to HDFS as a JSON file but Spark omits the fields that are null while writing the JSON. This is understandable as [`ignoreNullFields` is set to `true` by default](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L764)

But even when I use

```
spark.write.option("ignoreNullFields", "false").json(...)
```

or

```
spark.write.option("ignoreNullFields", false).json(...)
```

Columns containing null values get omitted.

Is there something that I'm missing while using the `ignoreNullFields` option?

Comment: wouldnt you be setting that to false if it is default true?

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi It was set to `false`. There was a typo in my question.

Comment: Support for including nulls when writing json seems to be relatively new: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26098 so make sure to check your version.

Comment: it looks for spark 3.0

Answer (score 3):

works when you put it as a configuration setting in the `SparkSession`

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the [ignoreNullFields](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#json-java.lang.String-) option correctly

the correct way is :

```py
df.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').json(ignoreNullFields=False,path="a")
```

to keep also the columns that contain only null values

Answer (score 0):

For people from the future: Utilizing **PySpark 3.2.1**, the original "problematic" solution works now. We can use ignoreNullFields as an option on the Writer:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [
[1, "2022-07-08 01:55:58", 1657238158],
[2, "2022-07-08 01:55:52", None],
[None, "2022-07-08 01:55:44", 1657238144],
]
columns = ["id", "ts_str_berlin", "ts_unix"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)

df.write.mode("overwrite").option("ignoreNullFields", False).json("./data/testjson/")
```

Exemplary JSON file content:

```
{"id":2,"ts_str_berlin":"2022-07-08 01:55:52","ts_unix":null}
```